# Keychain access not found for docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just started using docker. I am trying to login using the command line but getting an error due to keychain access. I selected the option "Securely store Docker login in macOS keychain" but still getting an error. How can i solve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your .docker/cofig.json and change it to "credsStore": "desktop". Restart docker

```
swapnil$ Downloads : cat $HOME/.docker/config.json
{
    "auths": {

    },
    "credsStore": "desktop",
    "experimental": "disabled",
    "stackOrchestrator": "swarm"
}swapnil$ Downloads :
```